# Proper way to name and declare nested crud pages in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I need to know how to properly structure my nested crud routes.

I currently have a working mockup in jsbin (see below), the problem however is that I could only get an 'add/user' route setup by using a generic 'add' route, which would conflict with other routes, controllers, etc.

I tried using users.add in the Route with App.UsersAddRoute, but to no avail.

**Routes**

```
// User Routes
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' });
    this.resource('add');
  });
});
```

**works with:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="add">
  <h1>Add user!</h1>
</script>
```

I need `add` to be `user.add` or something that is less ambiguous.

Thanks

http://jsbin.com/kahaq/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be `user.add`, you can either change it from a resource to a route (which I think it appropriate) or just call it `user.add`.

```
this.resource('users', function(){
    this.route('add');
});
```

Or

```
this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('users.add', function() {

    });
});
```

From the info I have, it seems like you should change both `add` and `user` to be routes, not resources.

Comment: Hi GJK, I've already added the resource user.add, problem it doesn't detect my handlebar file users.add.hbs?